# C# regex formula

Tags: c#, regex

For the following line, I need a regex to get the values outside the double quotes, namely: `0.0` and `100.5`.

```
"VAL_ 344 PedalPos 0.0 \"% (0.0 ... 100.0)\" 100.5 \"Invalid - Undefined (100.5 ... 127.5)\";"
```

Using this rule `Regex.Match(line, "\"\\s[0-9]+\\s\"")`, I am getting one group and that's the first value: `0.0`. I can't figure out how to extend the search to include all the following values.

Taking into consideration this part `[0-9]`, I think this only applies to integer values, I've added a dot there `[0-9.]` and this included the entire double numbers. Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: It looks like you also want to extract `344`, right?

Comment: @stribizhev, no .. that value is an Id. It shouldn't be added.

Comment: And what is the criterion for the IDs? Always after a `VAL_`? Please clarify.

Comment: \s?\d+(\.\d{1,2}) this should work,  tested here ... http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @stribizhev a format like this : VAL_ 344 PedalPos is found on every line, VAL_ as a constant string, an integer value as the ID and the next is a string, meaning the friendly name for that ID. And after them, pairs like : 0.0 "% (0.0 ... 100.0)" or 100.5 "Invalid - Undefined (100.5 ... 127.5)" are found.

Comment: In your case the following regex will work:

    `([\d\.]+)\s+\\"`

After character escaping:
    
    `([\\d\\.]+)\\s+\\\\"`

You will get two captured groups, which you can access by index.

I've checked it on http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

1) Remove all the quoted strings,

2) Extract all numbers that are not preceded by `VAL_`.

```
var txt = "VAL_ 344 PedalPos 0.0 \"% (0.0 ... 100.0)\" 100.5 \"Invalid - Undefined (100.5 ... 127.5)\";";
txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"""[^""]*""", string.Empty);
var results = Regex.Matches(txt, @"(?<!VAL_\s+)-?\b\d*\.?\d+\b");
```

Output:

[image]

Regex explanation:

- `"[^"]*"` - Match a quoted string
- `(?<!VAL_\s+)\b\d*\.?\d+\b`:

  - `(?<!VAL_\s+)` - A negative lookbehind to check if the number is not preceded with the constant `VAL_` string and 1 or more spaces
  - `\b\d*\.?\d+\b` - Match a whole word that is a floating number (a bit simplified, but it will even work with `.04`-like values).

Comment: I hope my explanation is good. And the question is by no means a duplicate.

Comment: @Rawling: Downvoting valid answers is BAD. I test my answers before posting. You do not like the question? Downvote the question.

Comment: I am sorry that some of the important details were mentioned in the comments. Indeed i didn't pay enough attention, i was just concentrated to my values and missed that first integer after the VAL_. But this answer gives the expected result and i thank  stribizhev twice, once for its formula and also for his question about the 344 value.

Comment: Late question: i can't find the way to get negative values also. In this case -100.5.

Comment: I have added the support for negative values by adding an optional minus sign to the regex: `@"(?<!VAL_\s+)-?\b\d*\.?\d+\b"`.

Comment: i've tried that -? everywhere but in front of that boundary ..thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"\s(\d+\.?\d*)\s"` (`string regex = "\"\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d*)\\s\"";` in code) and take the first group's result.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach that uses a single expression to get the numbers you need as I understand it:

```
@"VAL_\s*\d+|""[^""]+""|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```

How is works is that it actually matches the parts you don't want first without doing much to it, and when it comes to the last part, it uses a capture group to get what you actually need. Here's a snippet for how to use it:

```
string text = "VAL_ 344 PedalPos 0.0 \"% (0.0 ... 100.0)\" 100.5 \"Invalid - Undefined (100.5 ... 127.5)\";";
var re = new Regex(@"VAL_\s*\d+|""[^""]+""|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var textmatches = re.Matches(text);
Console.WriteLine("Result:");
foreach (Match match in textmatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/EYwFyJ)

`VAL_\s*\d+` matches `VAL_` followed by optional spaces and digits for the IDs,

`""[^""]+""` gets all within double quotes,

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` and finally this gets the numbers. I used a basic one, so if you have more complex numbers (negatives, scientific format, etc), you'll have to change that accordingly.

Comment: This ought to be more efficient than using two regex and works even if what you have between parentheses contain more than 2 numbers separated by spaces.